# 'OT1/xcmss/b/n' undefined using 'OT1/xcmss/bx/n' instead

Tags: fonts

Any idea how to remove this warning?

I am using the default sans serif font and compiling with pdfLaTeX in the book class.  I'm also using small caps sansmathfonts.

All of the lines where these warnings show up seem fine, so I can't pinpoint the issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}                                              
\usepackage{slantsc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Lorem Ipsum} is simply dummy text of the {\fontseries{bx}printing} 
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

\end{document}
```

Comment: the substituation looks ok, you can probably ignore the warning.

Comment: I will.  I think you are right.  I see no ill effects.  I only wish I knew what caused it.

Comment: Fonts can't provide every variant and the LaTeX font system had an in built substitution system just for this. b (bold) to bx (bold extended) sounds ok, but you didn't provide example code so I didn't check the details.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer MWE added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s harmless.  For historical reasons, Computer Modern calls its bold fonts `bx`, for Bold Extended.

In NFSS, there are four font parameters: the encoding (OT1, or the original 7-bit TeX encoding), the font family (`cmss`, Computer Modern Sans Serif), the shape (`n`, `i`, or sometimes something else like small caps or upright italic) and the series.  The latter combines weight (`b` for bold) and width (`x` for extended).  This naming scheme dates back to when MS-DOS limited all filenames to be eight characters, a dot, and a three-character file type, so they had to be terse.

You can remove this by changing `\bfseries` commands, probably in your hearder formats, to [`\fontseries{bx}`](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf#subsection.2.2), or by choosing a different font.

You could replace `\textbf{...}` with `{\fontseries{bx}...}` or create a macro

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bxseries}{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbx}{\fontseries{bx}}
```

and use `\bxseries` and `\textbx` in place of `\bfseries` and `\textbf`, respectively.

But the best solution of all would be to update to LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`, which lets you use modern fonts.  That instantly clears out a lot of technical debt from last century.

**ETA:** Now that you’ve added a MWE: the issue is coming from `sansmathfonts`.  If I change `\bfseries` to `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont` in TeX Live 2020, the warning also vanishes.

**ETA:** You need `\selectfont` after `\fontseries` for it to take effect.

Comment: I don't have the command \bfseries but I do have \textbf{...}.  Could that be it?  If so, what is its replacement?

Comment: @E2R0NS Edited.

Comment: I tried changing \textbf{...} to {textseries{bx}...} but I'm getting an undefined control sequence.

Comment: @E2R0NS That’s because I should have said [`\fontseries`](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf). My bad. Will fix.

Comment: Changing to \fontseries{bx} did not give me an error but it also didn't print in bold.  And the same original warning showed up so it was like it had no effect.

Comment: @E2R0NS Huh. Then I’d just ignore it. Or just `\usepackage{fontspec}` and solve every problem with 8-bit legacy encodings in one stroke.

Comment: I found more instances of \textbf so that did take care of the warnings.  But they are still not printing in bold.

Comment: But fontspec requires LuaLaTeX which I can't switch to right now.

Comment: Remember too that I'm in sans serif.

Comment: @E2R0NS `fontspec` works just fine in sans-serif. What surprises me is that you’re in OT1 with xcmss. That suggests it’s some package you’re loading, but you gave no MWE.

Comment: Added an MWE.  Perhaps it's \familydefault or sansmathfonts or both.

Comment: @E2R0NS It’s `sansmathfonts`, and changing every `\texbf`, `\bfseries` and `\fontseries{b}` fixes it.

Comment: It does not show up bold to me.  I changed ```\textbf{Lorem Ipsum}``` to ```{\fontseries{bx}Lorem Ipsum}``` and still nothing is bold in the MWE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110381/discussion-between-davislor-and-e2r0ns).

Answer (score 4):

The warning is harmless and you can safely ignore it. With a current LaTeX (2020-02-02) you can tell LaTeX that you want to use bx by default:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[sf]{bf}{bx}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Lorem Ipsum} is simply dummy text of the {\bfseries printing}
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.